# Promise.all Not Loading Images in React For Use In HTML Canvas

Tags: html, reactjs, promise, html5-canvas

I am building a small game in HTML canvas in React. For that, I need to pre-load all the images before I start interacting with the canvas API. I am loading all of the images using Promise.all like follows:

```
import tile from '../assets/images/tile.png';
componentDidMount() {
  this.load();
 }

loadImages(images) {
  return images.map(image => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const image = new Image();

      image.onload = () => {
        this.loadedImages.tile = image; //this.loadedImages is an instance variable
        resolve(image);
      };

      image.src = image;
    });
  });
}

load() {
  Promise.all(this.loadImages([tile]))
    .then(a => console.log(a))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
 }
```

All of the images exist in the source directory of the project. I am not sure if Promises are used to load them since they are not fetched from web. Anyways, `Promise.all` in `load` method does not resolve all the promises so it does not print any of the logs in thenables/catch. However, I can able to resolve a single promise like follows:

```
 loadImage($image) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const image = new Image();

    image.onload = () => {
      this.loadedImages.tile = image;
      resolve(image);
    };

    image.src = $image;
  });
}

load() {
  this.loadImage(tile)
    .then(a => console.log(a)) //prints the image element - a
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
 }
```

Please someone help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: I suspect you have an error with loading one of the images, but since the promise you create in the iteration doesn't implement reject it fails silently. I would add a reject to the promise and see whether that will tell you anything more.

Comment: right, but the single promise resolution works so I assumed it wont reject. @ChristianFritz

Comment: @ChristianFritz Is promises an acceptable way to load images from relative path?

Comment: I think so, yes. Loading files and managing asynchronicity (promise or callbacks) are two pretty different tasks. They are pretty independent of one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
      image.src = image;
```

This can't work! And since you don't have a `reject` in the inner promise, you don't hear about this error. In the single-image example you use `$image` to distinguish the two images.

Just rename one of your two `image` variables.

```js
loadImages(images) {
  return images.map(imageFile => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const image = new Image();

      image.onload = () => {
        this.loadedImages.tile = image; //this.loadedImages is an instance variable
        resolve(image);
      };

      image.src = imageFile;
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a [`reject()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) function. You should have one to debug such errors.

Also, you use two different variables with the same name (`image`) on the same scope.

You are requiring a single image file, and as such you absolutely doesn't need to create an array or much less an array of Promises.

Finally, consider using async/await syntax. It's clearer, easier to debug and to understand, and its syntax is React-compatible.